# Create combo box in python GTK 3.0 where the input of the first box changes the possible input choices for the second box

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk3, pygobject

I am looking to create a combo box in GTK where the user selected choice in the first box changes the choices available in the next boxes; ie if the first box contained manufacturers names, the next box would contain products of that manufacture, furthering that example if I selected bmw I could only select cars made by bmw. I know what the basic structure should look like, however I am not sure how to have the signals trigger one another. If someone could provide basic code or pseudo code that would be perfect .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to have one `manufacturer` model and many `product` models. When manufacturer is changed, combobox will emit `"changed"` signal. In it's handler you can set appropriate model to the second combobox using `set_model()` method.

Answer (score -1):

You can find a simple example in 14.1. at provided link:
http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/combobox.html

Comment: I know how to use the combo box for multiple individual drop downs but that’s not what I’m looking for. I need the 2nd drop down options list to be dependent on the drop down from the first